# What better to use to cache search results in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

So I have search on site. When user searches for example for `foo` I need to save `foo` and all the posts data related to `foo`. Not the ID, but all the info (title, description and etc). Basically I need to have something like:

```
{
    'foo': [
        {'title': 'foo', 'description': 'foo'},
        {'title': 'foo', 'description': 'foo'},
        {'title': 'foo', 'description': 'foo'}
    ],
    'bar': [
        {'title': 'bar', 'description': 'foo'},
        {'title': 'foo', 'description': 'bar'},
        {'title': 'bar', 'description': 'foo'}
    ]
}
```

At first I tried `Redis` but he immediately gave me a some problems. Most of them I somehow managed to sort, bu for example I just cant get all list of hashes like `search:foo:*` or `search:bar:*`.

So now I'm sure if I should use `Redis` or simply use `MongoDB`. Will be there a big difference in performance if I use `MongoDB` instead of `Redis` on big lists of data?

Comment: Redis is not meant to be a searchable database.

You can go build the request result directly from MongoDB, and then store it into the Redis instance. This way, when another user will search the exact same word, you can fetch the formatted result directly from Redis and return it to the user without building it again from the database.

Redis is key value cache store, the key is your search term and the value is the final output

Answer (score 0):

> Redis will give more performance as its in-memory, Nevertheless have
>   you tried MongoDB 3.2? its performance is superb and should be good if
>   its serve your purpose.
>
> Otherwise, you have a option of in memory DB like redis or your own
>   data structures